# strcpy runtime error / non-empty destination

Tags: c, string, runtime-error, strcpy

could you tell me why strcpy produces a runtime error here? Should the destination string be empty? And if so, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* input = "Nascartestdriver"; // strlen(input) == 16
  char* output = "asdfdhsghsdfasdf"; // strlen(output) == 16

  strcpy(output, input);
  printf("%s\n", output);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider adding detailed information on the error to your question.

Comment: @cel Do you really need more information to find this bug? This question is asked like 10 times per day.

Comment: @Lundin, Oh right, this was not really necessary here. I just triaged the question and didn't even have a closer look at the code, I just noticed the missing error message.

Answer (score 0):

Because `strcpy()` tries to write on read-only section.